# OpenCV and CMake in Windows7: wrong include dir

Tags: linux, windows, opencv, include, cmake

I built my own OpenCV-2.4.10 libs for Windows 7 mingw:

> 1) download opencv-2.4.10 for Windows to f:\opencv-2.4.10\
>
> 2) cmake f:\opencv-2.4.10\source to f:\opencv-2.4.10\build\x86\mingw
>
> 3) generate f:\opencv-2.4.10\build\x86\mingw
>
> 4) mingw32-make f:\opencv-2.4.10\build\x86\mingw

When I create an eclipse project, I set the include dir to `f:\opencv-2.4.10\build\include` and lib dir to `f:\opencv-2.4.10\build\x86\mingw\bin`

Everything works fine. Now I want to process the same project on Windows and Ubuntu and I created a CMake project for this. Under Windows I can cmake my project but I can't compile because the include files can't be find. I found out, that in my CMake project the include dir is set to `f:\opencv-2.4.10\source\include` and not to `f:\opencv-2.4.10\build\include`, that has another directory structure.

Under Ubuntu the project is compiled and works. So I'm pretty sure, that the problem is with my OpenCV installation on Windows. What did I do wrong, since this is the proposed procedure by the opencv documentation?

Answer (score 0):

```
f:\opencv-2.4.10\build\include
```

this holds the header files you want to include, it shouldn't matter if you are on windows or on Ubuntu